# Do I need to put named queries in ORM.xml file

Tags: orm, openjpa, entity-bean

I recently F-ed up my JPA entites and I am trying desperately to get that functionality back.  After adding some default queries to my my entities I can't call them in my session bean... I am getting this exception

```
There is no query with the name "" defined for any of the known persistent classes:
```

While the said named query does exist it is simply an annotation to a the persistence class (or entity bean).  Do I need to add that to the ORM.xml file?  I seem to remember that you could annotations to the ORM.xml file or you could directly annotate the entity bean.  am I missing a step here?

thanks.

UPDATE:
Actual Named queries:

```
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;

@Entity
@Table(name="EMAIL_DOMAIN_TRUST")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="getEmailDomainTrust", query = "SELECT e FROM EmailDomainTrust e"),
    ...
})
```

Here is where I call it in my stateless session bean

```
public List<EmailDomainTrust> getEmailDomains() {       

    List listOfEmailDomains = null;
    //try
    //{
        System.out.println("Testing 1..2...3...!");
        listOfEmailDomains = emf.createNamedQuery("getEmailDomainTrust").getResultList(); 
        System.out.println(listOfEmailDomains.size());
    //}
    //catch(Exception e)
    //{
        //System.out.println("Sugar Cookies!  This thing doesn't work");        
    //}
    // while(it)
   return listOfEmailDomains;
```

}

Do not know why it can't seem to find it?  I am working in Websphere integration developer btw.  Maybe something isn't updating correctly?

Comment: Please, update this post with more meaningful information. ie: Actual exception text, relevant Entity / orm snippets.

Comment: Have you listed your persistent types in your persistence.xml file? Do you have a typo in your post? EntityManagerFactory(emf) doesn't have a createNamedQuery(...) method (Or maybe I'm jumping to conclusions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.  I was being an idiot and not building my project.